# How to optimize stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Following is my Stored Proc.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [GetHomePageObjectPageWise]
       @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@PageCount INT OUTPUT
      ,@AccountID INT
      ,@Interests Varchar(3000)
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;



      SELECT StoryID
      , AlbumID
      , StoryTitle
      , CAST(NULL as varchar) AS AlbumName
      , (SELECT URL FROM AlbumPictures WHERE (AlbumID = Stories.AlbumID) AND (AlbumCover = 'True')) AS AlbumCover
      , Votes
      , CAST(NULL as Int) AS PictureId
      , 'stories' AS tableName
      , (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT NestedStories.StoryID FROM NestedStories WHERE (StoryID = Stories.StoryID) AND (AccountID=@AccountID)
        )
        THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END) AS Flag
      , (SELECT UserName FROM UserAccounts WHERE Stories.AccountID=UserAccounts.AccountID) AS Username

INTO #Results1
FROM Stories WHERE FREETEXT(Stories.Tags,@Interests) AND AccountID <> @AccountID AND IsActive='True' AND Abused < 10
```

I have 7 more `SELECT` Statements (not included in the question for brevity) in the Stored Proc similar to `SELECT StoryID` statement, which i `UNION ALL` like this

```
SELECT * INTO #Results9 FROM #Results1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #Results2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #Results3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #Results4
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #Results5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #Results6
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #Results7
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #Results8

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (
                  ORDER BY [tableName] DESC
            )AS RowNumber
            , * INTO #Results
            FROM #Results9


      DECLARE @RecordCount INT
      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM #Results

      SET @PageCount = CEILING(CAST(@RecordCount AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / CAST(@PageSize AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))


      SELECT * FROM #Results
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #Results
      DROP TABLE #Results1
      DROP TABLE #Results2
      DROP TABLE #Results3
      DROP TABLE #Results4 
END
```

This takes around 6 seconds to return the result. How can i improve this stored proc? I have very little knowledge about stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Raise a nonclustered index on columns in `where` clause, `IsActive`, `AccountID` and `Abused`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can only optimize it by getting rid of the temporary tables. Your approach sucks not because it is a stored procedure (so the SP part is simply totally irrelevant) but because you do a lot of temporary table stuff that forces linear execution and makes it hard for the query optimizer to find a better day to go forward.

In this particular case, it may be that your db design may be horrifically bad (why #result 1 to #result 8 to start with) and then you have tons of "copy into temp table" on every stored procedure.

Query Optimization in SQL works "statement by statement" and execution is never paralleled between statements - so the temp table stuff really gets into your way here. Get rid of the temp tables.

Comment: And how can i get rid of the temp tables? Can you give me a short example?

Answer (score 0):

Never ever use directly SELECT * INTO #temp
INSTEAD
Always create #temp tables then INSERT INTO #temp 
this will reduce query execution time by 70%

Though it might be frustration to create #temp table with exact structures,
so here is a short cut for that:This will be once performed

CREATE dbo.tableName by using SELECT * INTO tableName from Your calling query
then
sp_help TableName will provide structures.
Then create #temp table in Store Procedure.

I have optimized query for one of our client which was taking 45 minutes to execute, just replaced with this logic It worked !!!
Now it takes 5 Minutes !!

Comment: Can you give me an example for my question?

Comment: In your case #Results1 temp table is being created by Select * INTO #Results1, instead at beginning create table #Results1 by using create command.